# Can We resize the UIDatePicker View in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want a UIDatePicker View in a smaller size with respect to what it comes with. Is it possible to resize it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a commonly asked question here:

- [How to change UIPickerView height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573979/how-to-change-uipickerview-height)
- [UIPicker sizing in landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535164/uipicker-sizing-in-landscape-mode)
- [how to shrink picker view in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905969/how-to-shrink-picker-view-in-iphone)

It's not a control that likes to be resized, but you can play some tricks with its frame or with the frame of a UIView you've placed it in.  As I [describe here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905969/how-to-shrink-picker-view-in-iphone/906985#906985), the cleanest way I've found to resize this control is by placing it within a hosting UIView, then applying an affine transform to scale that hosting view down.