# for autorotation for any view

Tags: iphone

when UIDatepicker rotates from portrait to landscape mode,
my UIDatepickerview not autoresizes.though i'm using autoresizingmask property too

Answer (score 0):

The date picker is a fixed size, 320 x 216.

Thyere are tricks that you can play, using affine transforms and masking but I doubt that this is what you want.

See: [UIPicker sizing in landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535164/uipicker-sizing-in-landscape-mode/535176#535176/)