# UIPickerView Height customisation

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

Need to display 4 UIPickerView in ViewController.

How can i customise height?

Minimum height we can given is 162.
Can i give 100 height for each UIPickerView?
Is there any framework or example available?

Comment: Use contentSize property of UIPopoverController to set size of the popover.
Do you need to display all four popovers at the same time?

Comment: sorry..i edited my question..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
picker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
CGSize ps = [picker sizeThatFits: CGSizeZero];
picker.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, ps.width, ps.height + 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code, it may be work in you case:

```
self.MyPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
```

For Other tips check This Answer

[UIPicker sizing in landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535164/uipicker-sizing-in-landscape-mode/535176#535176)

Answer (score 0):

For `UIPickerView` there are only three Height : 162,180,216. You can use `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation` and `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` for properly fit to picker.

```
CGAffineTransform t;
CGAffineTransform s;
CGAffineTransform u;
UIPickerView *pickerview;

t = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation (0, pickerview.bounds.size.height);
s = CGAffineTransformMakeScale (1.0,0.5);
u = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation (0 ,pickerview.bounds.size.height);
pickerview.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat (t, CGAffineTransformConcat(s,u));
```

Here the above code changes the height of picker view.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind clipping the ends, you can embed it inside of a smaller view, with clipping enabled.